# select last word in a sentence having a specific word

Tags: regex

In the below output I need to search the line having `REGEXX` and in that line I need to select the last word. In the below example it's `YYY-0`. How do I do it?

```
 LOGICAL FILE MODIFIED:

 SYSTEM = x-YYY   UNIT = ALU

 PAGE      1
 LOG       LOG       SPARE  PHYSICAL           OBJ  SYSTEM     UNIT    DEVICE/
 FILE      FILE      FILE   FILE               IND   NAME      NAME    LOGICAL
 NBR  NAME  &  CLASS MODE   NAME                                        FILE

 1FF REGEXX   P                              1 X-YYY       ALU     YYY-0


 COMMAND EXECUTED
```

Comment: Which language are you using for this? Why do you need a regex for this? It seems the same thing can be achieved with simple (and fast) string functions.

Comment: What did you try?  This isn't a code request site.

Comment: @TimPietzcker The framework used in the project, forces me to use regex

Comment: [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) has some amazing information on learning regular expressions.  I suggest you learn them :-)

Comment: Finally was able to get the desired output by using ^.*REGEXX\s*.* (\S+)\s+$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this pattern in multiline mode:

```
\bREGEXX(?:[^\S\r\n]+\S+)*[^\S\r\n]+(\S+)[^\S\r\n]*$
```

*(The result is in the first capuring group)*

or more simple but with more backtracks:

```
\bREGEXX\b.*?(\S+)[^\S\r\n]*$
```

Notice: As Tim Pietzcker suggests it, you will have better result with simple string functions. You can split your text by line, and after by spaces, and then loop inside the array/list to find `REGEXX`

Comment: Thanks for your time. Out of the 3 answers given, this one is very near to the working solution :  ^.*REGEXX\s*.* (\S+)\s+$

Answer (score 1):

```
\bREGEXX\b.*\s(\S+)
```

Something like the above will search for 'REGEXX'  and then capture the last non-blank string following it. Your last 'word' (actially, sequence of non-blank characters) will be available in capture group 1.

Answer (score 1):

If awk is at hand, you can try this:

```
awk '/REGEXX/ {print $NF}'
```

where `NF` is 'number of fields' in the current string, $1, $2, ..., $NF are space/tab separated fields.